# Can we convert Jmeter report in Allure report?

Tags: jmeter, report, allure

I want to convert Jmeter performance test result in Allure report for better understanding of reports or better summarized reports

Answer (score 2):

You can run your JMeter tests via [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation/) tool and configure it to produce [JUnit XML reports](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/#JUnit-XML-Reporter).

Example configuration:

```
execution:
  - scenario: jmeter

scenarios:
jmeter:
script: test.jmx

reporting:
  - module: junit-xml
filename: result.xml
data-source: sample-labels
```

Once you run your test like:

```
bzt test.yaml
```

you will get `result.xml` file in the current folder. And it would be enough to invoke [`allure serve .` command](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_report_generation) to generate Allure reports from the JUnit-style XML result file.

Comment: Thanks @DmitriT..I am able to generate the allure report.